# Random generated color code not accepting in TailwindCSS in React.Js

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

Here is my Messages component :

```
import randomColor from "random-color";
import React from "react";
import "../Chat.css";

function Messages({username , msg}) {
  const changeTextColor = randomColor(0.99, 0.99).hexString();
  console.log(changeTextColor);
  return (
    <div className="flex-1 px-5 py-2 chatting_body  ">
      <div className="flex flex-col px-4 py-2 bg-slate-600 border rounded-md max-w-fit ">
        <div className={`text-sm font-bold text-[${changeTextColor}] `}>{username}</div>
        <div className="flex justify-between items-end space-x-3 ">
          <p className="text-white text-lg ">{msg}</p>
          <p className="text-gray-400 text-xs " >{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Messages;
```

By just   `console.log(changeTextColor);` I'm getting the Hexcode, but tailwind can't able to fetch.

Comment: You can't have dynamic classes with tailwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use runtime dynamic value in tailwind, for this I would recommend using custom properties.

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/rssilvaba/pen/XWPZYyW).

```html
<div class="flex-1 px-5 py-2 chatting_body  ">
  <div class="flex flex-col px-4 py-2 bg-slate-600 border rounded-md max-w-fit ">
    <div class="text-sm font-bold text-[var(--changeTextColor,black)]">{username}</div>
    <div class="flex justify-between items-end space-x-3 ">
      <p class="text-white text-lg ">{msg}</p>
      <p class="text-gray-400 text-xs ">{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="rounded bg-blue-400 p-2">change color</button>
```